# How to limit entity list-property size with JPQL?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpql, java-ee-7

I have this query in JPQL

```
FROM User u INNER JOIN FETCH u.addresses a WHERE u.id =:id ORDER BY a.id DESC
```

Sometimes a user may have more than ten addresses and I want to limit this to ten. If the user wants to he may load more ten adresses later.

I tried using [setMaxResults(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#setMaxResults(int)) but I wasn't sucessfull because since I get only one user I think jpql understands it as it is right even if the query translated and used in my database brings me more than one result.

Is it possible to to what I want? If so, how?

**EDIT:**

I have the SQL that brings me what I want, but I want this in [jpql](/questions/tagged/jpql) if possible.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    user u INNER JOIN address a ON u.id_user = a.id_user
WHERE
    u.id_user = '123' AND ROWNUM = 1
ORDER BY
    a.id_address desc;
```

Comment: You need to query the Address directly then setMaxResults(int) will work. FROM Address a JOIN a.user u WHERE u.id = :userId

Comment: But this will not bring me user information, right?

Comment: You will need an User mapping in your Address Class.

Comment: The query you suggested me gave me as answer an Object[] with two positions. The first one containing the last address and the second containing the user with all the addresses. Take a look at my edit, perhaps the SQL makes my doubt clearer.

Comment: @PhilippeGioseffi: what you're asking is not possible (and not desirable). When JPA gives you a user, it's a user. Not half of a user. So if you ask for the user's addresses, you'll get the user's addresses. Not half of his addresses. You may use another object containing a reference to a user and a list of half of his addresses if you want, populated by a query as the one bzzzrd gave you.